# how can i use $interval in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, setinterval

**Hi i want to run $interval in the for loop**

what i did

- i implemented below code for auto refreshing
- i am] checking data array with status queued object
- then i am calling    refresh instance (it is an ajax call to get the
  status of the    instance)
- but suppose if there are more than one instance having queued as    a
  status then refreshing the instnace with last one

**what i wnat 
i want to refresh all the isntnaces**

**ex:**

```
data=[{id:1,status:'queued'},{id:2,status:'active'},{id:3,status:'queued'},{id:4,status:'active'},{id:5,status:'queued'}];
```

**then id:5 instnace is only refreshing but i want all the instaces like 1,3,5**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{   
  if(data[i].status =='queued')
  {
    var id = data[i].id;
    promiseObj[id] = $interval( function(){ $scope.refreshInstance('active',id); }, 20000);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the use of a [closure inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

But in this case you can fix it using a much easier [forEach()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) loop

```
angular.forEach(data, function (item, idx) {
    if (item.status == 'queued') {            
        promiseObj[item.id] = $interval(function () {
            $scope.refreshInstance('active', item.id);
        }, 20000);
    }
});
```